# cursor.execute() invalid syntax error when exporting data to SQL Server - column name starts with a number

Tags: sql, pandas, pyodbc

I am exporting data from pandas Dataframe to SQL Server using Pyodbc. I have a problem, faced for the first time - that when I insert into a SQL Server column with a name that starts with a number - `5star` -  the for loop doesn't capture the name of the column, highlights number as it was not part of the column name and returns 'invalid syntax' error.

The code is visible below, was working perfectly when column name wasn't starting from a number.

```
for index, row in merged3.iterrows(): 
     cursor.execute("INSERT INTO database.rating (overall, 5star, 4star) values(?,?,?)", row.overall, row.5star, row.4star)
database.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Any ideas how to improve it, without changing the name of the column in the database itself?

Comment: Can you share the exact error and full traceback of the error?

Comment: A typical column name starts with a letter, as in `five_star`. If you want to use `5star` as a column name, then you'll need to enclose it in brackets, as in `[5star]`. Though it will work, every time you mention the column from now on you'll need to write it that way.

Comment: ipython-input-98-214c5123c765

Comment: @TheImpaler when I added brackets, the invalid syntax error still exists with the following traceback ipython-input-99-b65b8d1945ad

Comment: @AleksandraZajączkowska If your database is SQL Server, then it should work well. See example at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ec99c52b5fdedac95f1cfb91a58ab6e3

Comment: @TheImpaler I think the issue lies in part "... row.5star, row.4star" - in this part also number is highlighted like it wasn't part of the column name - when I remove it, it works again well. I tried to add brackets also in these "row. " parts but still it returns "invalid syntax" error.

Comment: Look like a python/pyodbc issue. Not my expertise I'm afraid.

Comment: Instead of `row.5star` try `row["5star"]`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `sqlalchemy`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=(localDb)\ProjectsV14;DATABASE=database")
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))

merged3.to_sql('rating', schema='dbo', con = engine)
```